# Do greater probabilities approach expected average values with a smaller series?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

Let's say you flip a coin 12 times with a goal of getting 6 heads.  Then you roll a six sided die 12 times with a goal of getting 2 "ones" faces up.  My intuition tells me that rolling the dice has a greater chance of failing to hit the goal, or to come close.

I know the Law of Large Numbers means that with an infinite sample we would trend towards the mean of both goals.  Not being able to run an infinite series of experiments I'm wondering if there is a way to forecast how many samples I need to run to reach my goal on average, and does that number of samples vary depending on the probability?

How do express this problem mathematically, and what math concepts do I need to study to understand this problem?

Comment: you might want to look into variation and standard deviation.

Answer (score 1):

I would study the [negative binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution), as it will describe both situations. In general, you should be familiar with how to compute expected values for discrete variables from their probability mass functions.